# How to change audio levels of sound card with same control names

Tags: raspbian, audio, raspbian-jessie, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying to write a script that automatically changes the playback/capture audio levels based on the device that is connected.

I'm using a MAYA44 USB+ sound with 4 ch in/out.

Thanks to a similar question here: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/97936/terminal-command-to-set-audio-volume

I learned to use the following command:

```
amixer -c 2 sset Line,1 50%
```

The problem I have is that it seems like the capture control shares the same name as a playback control: Line

[image]

Doing

```
amixer -c 2 sset Line 50%
```

Changes the values of BOTH controls.

As mentioned above, I'm writing a script to do this automatically so I don't want to manually go into alsamixer and do it manually.

Is there a way to rename the controls so that there isn't a naming clash? Otherwise, is there some sore of suffix or prefix I can add to the 'Line' value to specify that I want to affect the CAPTURE device? Would using pulse audio in some way be another option?

Basically, how I can change the capture control values without affecting the playback values?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `amixer -c2 controls` to list all the low-level controls.

Then you can use `amixer -c2 cset ..` to select specific controls by their unique ID number.

Comment: I tried this earlier and it failed... Having tinkered with it a bit more, I realized that in the line 
'numid=10, iface=MIXER, name='Line Capture Switch''
the unique id is in fact 'numid=10' instead of being 10!
This worked like a charm, I thank you CL.

Comment: Do you know if these unique IDs are consistent? Could I hardcode them into my script?

Comment: They might change with a different driver/kernel version.